# how to pass a variable by reference to a c function `sscanf()`

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

the following code tries to read the command line arguments and then scans them with `sscanf()` and use the result to emit utf8 text.

I'm failing to call `sscanf()` and getting segfault error at the line where I call this function

I have already debugged this and I know where is the problem but not how to solve it.

```
            global  main
            extern  puts
            extern  sscanf
            extern  printf
            extern  emit_utf_8

            section .text
main:

                        cmp rdi, 2
                        jl  argumentsError

                        add     rsi, 8                  ; skip the name of the program
forloop:
                        mov     r12, rsi
                        push    rdi                     
                        push    rsi
                        push    r12                     
                        sub     rsp, 8                  ; must align stack before call
                        ; start of for bloc

                        xor rax, rax
                        mov     rdi, qword [r12]              
                        mov     rsi, codePointFormat 
                        mov     rdx, qword [codePoint]
                        call    sscanf
                        cmp     rax, 1
                        je      ifthen
                        jmp     else
ifthen:
                        mov     rdi, codePoint
                        call    emit_utf_8
                        jmp     endif
else:
                        mov     rdi, incorrectFormat
                        mov     rsi, r12
                        call    printf
endif:                                          


                        ; end of for bloc
                        add     rsp, 8                  ; restore %rsp to pre-aligned value
                        pop     r12
                        pop     rsi                     
                        pop     rdi

                        add     rsi, 8                  ; point to next argument
                        dec     rdi                     ; count down
                        jnz     forloop                 ; if not done counting keep going

                        ret

argumentsError:     mov rdi, argumentsRequiredMessage
                    call    puts

                    mov rdi, argumentDescription
                    call    puts

                    xor rax, rax
                    inc rax
                    ret

            section .data
argumentsRequiredMessage:
                         db "This program requires one or more command line arguments,", 0
argumentDescription:     db "one for each code point to encode as UTF-8.", 0
incorrectFormat:         db "(%s incorrect format)", 0
codePointFormat:         db "U+%6X", 0

            section .bss
codePoint:      resb    8           ; The code point from sscanf should go here.
```

Is there a way to pass that third argument?

`sscanf()` signature.

`in __cdecl sscanf(const char *const _buffer, const char *const _Format, ...)`

I'm using ubuntu 19.04 64 bit

Comment: You just need to pass the address. Use `lea rdx, [codePoint]`

Comment: (Use `default rel` for Jester's suggestion to make sure you get a RIP-relative LEA)

Comment: @Jester I still get the segfault

Comment: @PeterCordes I will look that up and get back to you

Comment: You also have a typo: `section .data.` has an extra trailing dot. But that should probably not cause a fault. Check where the fault happens.

Comment: @Jester the typo is in this post because I removed some comments that were there. great catch by the way.

Comment: You also destroy `r12` which is a caller saved register. Depending on where the crash is that may be a cause. Your stack aligmnent actually misaligns the stack because `call` pushes another 8 bytes.

Comment: All that said, debugging shows the actual reason is that you iterate `argc` times but you skip the first argument so you process the terminating `NULL`. Make sure you run the loop one less times.

Comment: @Jester thank you very much I fixed all my mistakes. please post an answer so I could accept it. I had many problems and 3 days of experience. I have been coding nasm assembly for 10 hours now. so thank you for saving me from this. If you nkow any good resource that I could learn from that would be great.